# multiprocessing vs. multithreading for flask webserver

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, io, multiprocessing

So I am running a python script on my RaspberryPi which reads sensor data, and saves this data into a simple .csv. I am also running a dash webserver on the same raspberry pi, which reads the .csv data and publishes it to a webserver, and another script which reads the data and sends it live-stream over a lora radio interface.

Since all of these processes are reading from a shared resource (the .csv data file) I am wondering if it is better to use the python multiprocessing module, or the multithreading module? I read that multithreading is better to used when sharing memory resources and for I/O processes. Am I correct in my way of thinking?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I understand that you only read data from shared resource. If that correct then you don't want to use Multithreading. Problem only getting start when you are reading & writing data on shared resource and then you have to use Multithreading or Multiprocessing or some other method.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIN488Ldg9k
refer this video link to understand "Difference between Multiprocessing and Multithreading".

Comment: Ah yes, the issue is that some child processes are also writing to the shared resource.....therefore it is probably better to just use multithreading